# Does Gazprom or Russia confirm that one of the Nord Stream 2 pipes is still (theoretically) operational after the recent pipe breakage incidents?

Tags: russian-federation, gas, nord-stream

[According](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/09/28/world/europe/nordstream-pipeline-gas-leak-explosions.html) to the New York Times, during the recent mystery events, both pipes of Nord Stream 1 were severed, whereas only one of Nord Stream 2's pair was.

Does Gazprom or Russia confirm this state of affairs, i.e. is one remaining Nord Stream 2 pipeline still theoretically operational according to Gazprom/Russia? (I know Germany didn't give approval to open NS2.)

Comment: This seems more like a news question than a politics question.

Comment: Do you mean that Russians have blown their own pipeline... only to declare that it is still operational?

Comment: @RogerVadim: No, I'm not suggesting that. Whoever attacked the pipes (which seems the likely scenario according to governments on all sides right now) may well have planned to blow up all 4 pipes, but may (ironically) have failed to blow one. Or it may have been spared deliberately for some reason, who knows?! Since almost everything about this is surrounded in controversy and [reciprocal] finger pointing, I'm just asking if there's even agreement on what exactly was severed and what wasn't.

Comment: Yeah, Gazprom has confirmed this now https://www.upstreamonline.com/production/gazprom-makes-nord-stream-2-supply-gesture-even-as-italy-and-moldova-suffer-new-supply-woes/2-1-1325483 although they said they need to do a safety inspection on the pipe that still had pressure/gas in it, so they are depressurizing it ATM.